# Concatenar arrays acumulando conteúdos em C#

Tags: c#

Senhores, a questão é da linguagem de programação C #, minha pergunta é: como posso colocar todos os itens do array B dentro de cada item do array A e o resultado disso será armazenado no array C. Obrigado.

Agradeço desde já ...

```
public void TesteUniaoArray3()

{
    string[] one = new string[] { "XXXXX-X-XXX", "YYYYY-Y-YYY" };
    string[] two = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    string[] three;

    three = new string[one.Length * two.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i <= one.Length; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j <= two.Length; j++)
            for (int idx = j; idx <= two.Length; idx++)
                try
                {
                    three[idx] = one[i] + "-" + two[j++];
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    idx = three.Length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que fique claro o que pretende coloque o resultado esperado.

Comment: Resultado esperado na array three:

XXXXX-X-XXX-1,
XXXXX-X-XXX-2,
XXXXX-X-XXX-3,
XXXXX-X-XXX-4,
XXXXX-X-XXX-5,
YYYYY-Y-YYY-1,
YYYYY-Y-YYY-2,
YYYYY-Y-YYY-3,
YYYYY-Y-YYY-4,
YYYYY-Y-YYY-5

Comment: @CleberPessoal, bem vidno ao SOpt. Por favor, coloque o coteúdo relevante (como o resultado desejado) como parte da pergunta editando-a ao invés de comentar. Isso dará mais visibilidade e poermitirá que a comunidade saiba de forma rápida o ponto da questão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você usou um loop a mais, o que acabou lhe criando problema. É mais simples resolvendo dessa maneira:

```
string[] one = new string[] { "XXXXX-X-XXX", "YYYYY-Y-YYY" };
string[] two = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
string[] three;

three = new string[one.Length * two.Length];

int idx = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < one.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < two.Length; j++)
    {
        three[idx] = one[i] + "-" + two[j];
        idx++;
    }

//foreach(var i in three)
//  Console.WriteLine(i);
```

O resultado seria de acordo com o que você espera, como [pode conferir no dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YoeNq0)

Comment: Perfeito!!!!     Obrigado.